# Winter Bash 2015?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Ho ho ho, everyone.  [It's time for hats!](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com)  Here's the news from the powers that be:

> The end of the year is upon us, and here in Stack Land, that can only mean one thing: it's time for Winter Bash 2015!
>
> Winter Bash is a fun, lighthearted event we run every year as a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make our communities awesome. It's open to any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. During Winter Bash, users earn virtual hats by completing certain tasks. They're sort of like badges, but they're more visible and less permanent. Hats can be "worn" on users' avatars just about anywhere avatars show up on the network.

As with [last year](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219/winter-bash-2014-the-yays-have-it), individual members can opt out of the hats business by clicking on the "I hate hats" button on the footer.

Winter Bash will run from 14 December to 3 January.

### What do we need?

Your opinion, if you please.  **Should Emacs.SE participate as a site in Winter Bash?**

### What do you do?

Vote below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `t`

```
(when (hatp)
  (wear-fun-hats))
```

Comment: Welp, we had virtually no discussion of this, unlike last year.  The default setting network-wide is "on," so we're on.

Answer (score 1):

### `nil`

```
(when (grinchp)
  (steal-hoo-hash))
```